A TV show episode about a killer
I'm looking for a TV show, specifically an episode from it,about a man being "possessed" by a prisoner/killer's soul and kills his whole family. In the end the man gets his body back but his family is already dead except his kid (i think it was daughter) who is still alive. When the kid is asked who killed the family S/He points at the dad (even though it was the killer in the dads body).

When was it released?

several years ago... I don't know for sure but definitely 5 or more

I saw this, but am drawing a blank. The father/killer was a white maie, correct?

Yes!! He was a white male.

After a little more research I found what I was looking for. The TV series is called Fear Itself and the specific episode was season 1 episode 3 titled "Family Man."

Dennis Mahoney is an All-American dad: successful, loving, and all-around good guy. All that changes after a car accident leaves him hanging between life and death. He finds his way back to life... only to wake up in the body of a serial killer named Richard Brautigan, a.k.a. "The Family Man Killer." Even worse is that Brautigan is now in Mahoney's body. With time running out, Dennis must find a way to save his family from Brautigan's murderous intent before he is executed in Brautigan's place.


You might want to elaborate in which way this fits to the details from the question in order to flesh out the answer a little more.

And feel free to approve the answer (by clicking on the check mark next to it, thus marking it 'solved').

Might be 'Twin Peaks' from 1990-1991. The FBI agent and Twin Peaks police are trying to solve the murders.  The last 2 episodes reveal

 the father killed everyone by having the soul of a killer inside him.


Er, are you talking about Leland Palmer? Because that's not exactly what happened there...

No I don't think this was it. It was sort of like a crime tv show where it was different cases each episode I believe
